# Is it possible to get mat-menu opened position?

Tags: angular, angular-material

Could someone help me to detect a position of an opened menu? I need to apply styles for different position behavior. I've got a problem when there is no space to expand below it automatically expands above, how can I detect, that my menu items changed their position?

***Thanks in advance!***

Comment: is it mat-menu or you have created custom ?

Comment: @Dakopatel just a <mat-menu>

Comment: can you please add code and explain in detail what does exactly you want ?

Comment: @Dakopatel when menu is opened I need to know in  which way is opened is it above or below

Comment: Maybe this helps?
https://material.angular.io/components/menu/overview#customizing-menu-position

Comment: @mxr7350 nope(( I've already checked the documentation... If viewport has changed, mat-menu position changed to the allowed one (from bottom to top) and I can't detect it :(

Comment: you can define a variable into component.ts after the change the variable as per viewport is changed.

Comment: @Dakopatel thank you! I've added a host listener on resize with a function which counts the difference between two ViewChild anchors by clientY, by that I know in which way my dropdown is open

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks @Dakopatel for advice!

in html I've added #mainTrigger and #menuItems to get element refs:

```
<div class="flex align-center space-between"
   [matMenuTriggerFor]="dropdownMenu"
   #trigger="matMenuTrigger"
   (click)="getMenuPosition($event)"
   (menuClosed)="above = false;"
   #mainTrigger> 
</div>
<mat-menu #dropdownMenu="matMenu" class="drop-list">
<div class="menu-panel" #menuItems>
 // some for function here
</div>
```

in componet:

```
@ViewChild('menuItems') menuItems: any;
@ViewChild('mainTrigger') mainTrigger: ElementRef;
above: boolean;
@HostListener('window:resize', ['$event'])
getScreenSize(event?) {
  this.getMenuPosition();
}

constructor() {
   this.getScreenSize();
}

getMenuPosition() {
 setTimeout(() => {
    const main = this.mainTrigger.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect();
    const child = this.menuItems.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect();
    this.above = main.y > child.y;
   }, 100);
 }
```